# Validat Data on Date And Time Column not work on editform.aspx on sps 2010

Tags: 2010, date-time, validation

i have a pronlem on validation on edit mode of list items.
my a simple list have a column named : "StartTime" with date & time type.
and i add this validate rule : "=[Created]<[StartTime]" 
it is work on newform.aspx but on editform.aspx this not work and user can edit time to befor creation item! 
is this a bug on share point?
if yes or no is any way to control that "starttime" can not give a value smaller than "Created".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest two ways to fix that problem:

1. Add the calculated field in addition with "Created" field:

   - Create calculated field (for ex "CreatedDate") with Formula="=[Created]".
   - Change StartTime field's validation formula to "=[CreatedDate]<[StartTime]".
2. Or use TODAY() instead [Created] (If it will be suitable for you)

Comment: Not sure this is what he is looking for - he meant the VALIDATION Rules prior to updating items, not calculated columns!

Comment: waht is  "field instead of OOTB" ?

Comment: OOTB means Out of the box feature. I meant you need to add new calculated field. Not "instead", sorry, in addition with "Created". I updated my answer.

Comment: yeeeeeesss it's work.Really thank you dear @Andrew :)

Answer (score 0):

I asume you are trying to validate this at the column level? If so, this would not work as you are not allowed to use other fields. But what you could do is to create a validation formula at the List level and use the same formula, but without the EQUAL, basically in the Formula text area simply type [StartTime]>[Created] and then your message in case is wrong.

However, to my knowledge, validation using CREATED occurs only on NEW, but not on EDIT - so you might be out of luck. Using the MODIFIED could work, but not sure this would match your required logic.